# Change markup of attachment thumbs and links in posts

Tags: image, wordpress

When I insert an image into a post in Wordpress, the markup similar to this is inserted into the editor:

```
<a href="http://example.com/w-content/uploads/2014/01/image.jpg" rel="attachment wp-att-26">
    <img src="http://example.com/w-content/uploads/2014/01/image-100x100.jpg" 
         width="100" height="100" class="alignleft wp-image-26" />
</a>
```

How can I change that markup? I would like to use a `<figure>` tag for images, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out how to do this. The markup can be influenced using  the filter `image_send_to_editor`.